# Best way to manage fragments back stack and back button

Tags: android, android-fragments

I do need to handle the fragment back stack and the back button a little bit different than the normal way, which is a circle throw every fragment entry in the back stack.

Please, suppose you have a sliding menu with three items; Profile, Network and Workplaces.

Each one shows a ListFragment with a ListView and when you press onto an item you go to see it.

So the back stack gonna be like [list] <- [view]. The problem is that in the way that the back stack works (or my understanding of it, or the incorrect use I am doing) is as the user goes through the app pressing onto different items, them will add an entry to the back stack, it gets longer and longer and if the user wants to go to the home screen pressing on the back button needs to go to every single entry until the index 0; like this [list] <- [view] <- [list] <- [view], etc. etc.

My question is what is the best way to handle this requirement? Should I remove from the back stack every single fragment when the user select one of those items from the sliding menu? Should I have a back stack per menu item?

The achievement is that every menu item handles the back stack and when the user is on any of those list views and he press onto the back button he goes to the home screen. Easy navigation!

Any suggestion appreciated!

Comment: Should "throw" be "through"?

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is best practice in android to leave the back stack as is, so it is predictable to the user.  If a user enters your app from another app and hits the back button the user wants to go to the previous app not your apps home screen.  I would suggest thinking of another solution to the problem you want to solve, adding a drawer perhaps.

Hope I didn't miss interpret what you are trying to accomplish.

Cheers!

Comment: That is not the case. I meant the phone home screen as Android documentation. http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is a button that takes the user straight back to the home screen.  You can do this by using the Home button in the action bar. See [Providing Up Navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html) for details.

Comment: I meant the phone home screen, not the app home screen.

Comment: @Proverbio That is highly discouraged. If the user wants to go to the phone home screen, she can just press the Home button next to the Back button instead.

Comment: I agree. It could be much easy for me. But the problem is that many users use to go to the home screen using the back button instead, also the Google Android documentation says that. Please take a look at: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

Comment: @Proverbio Did **you** read the link you just gave me? "The system Back button is used to navigate, in reverse chronological order, through the history of screens the user has recently worked with."